# My player isn't showing when I run my Pygame project

Tags: python, pygame

I was programming player movement for my game and I'm not getting errors but the code isn't working correctly. The game is just presenting a black screen, if your able to help, please do that would be greatly appreciated! I've tried resetting my browser and such, but nothings working anyone able to help? (I'm using repl.it)

```py
import pygame, sys

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 400, 400
TITLE = "DarkRoom"

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
class Player:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
    self.x = int(x)
    self.y = int(y)
    self.color = (255, 255, 255)
    self.velX = 0
    self.velY = 0
    self.left_pressed = False
    self.right_pressed = False
    self.up_pressed = False
    self.down_pressed = False
    self.speed = 4
    
def draw(self, win):
  pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)
  def update(self):
    self.velX = 0
    self.velY = 0
    if self.left_pressed and not self.right_pressed:
      self.velX = -self.speed
      if self.right_pressed and not self.left_pressed:
        self.velX = self.speed
        if self.up_pressed and not self.down_pressed:
          self.velY = -self.speed
          if self.down_pressed and not self.up_pressed:
            self.velY = self.speed

          self.x += self.velX
          self.y += self.velY

          self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32)

player = Player(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)

while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.quit()
      sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        player.left_pressed = True
      if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        player.right_pressed = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
          player.up_pressed = True
      if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        player.down_pressed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
          if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player.left_pressed = False
      if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        player.right_pressed = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
          player.up_pressed = False
      if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        player.down_pressed = False
        
        win.fill((12, 24, 36))
        player.draw(win)

player.update()
pygame.display.flip()

clock.tick(120)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to draw the player and update the display in the application loop, but not after the application loop:

```py
while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    # [...]

# INDENTATION
#->|

  player.update()
  pygame.display.flip()

  clock.tick(120)
```